# apk name change not working cordova

Tags: cordova

I have made some change to get different name instead of ***android-debug.apk*** which is automatically generated after build. But the changes which I amde seems to be not working. Here is my ***build.gradle*** file which is generated after I create the android platform. Please check and tell me why its not working. Im running all these in command prompt not in android studio/eclipse.

```
    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }


buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig getSigningConfig()
                applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    variant.outputs.each { output ->
                        def date = new Date();
                        def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                                output.outputFile.name.replace("-release", "-" + formattedDate)
    //for Debug use output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
   //                             output.outputFile.name.replace("-debug", "-" + formattedDate)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}
```

Before I made changes to the ***buildType*** it was like this.

```
buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an answer today. It seems to working good as I expected. The changes what I made will share here below:

**1)** I have to **omit or delete** this particular session from the ***build.gradle*** file

```
if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
```

**2)** In the **buildTypes** make changes whatever you wanted as in **debug or release** method. Here I have made changes for the both and have got the answer I expected. Here is my **buildTypes**.

```
buildTypes  {
            debug(or release){
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
             project.ext { appName = 'YourName' }   
            def newName = output.outputFile.name.replace("android", "$project.ext.appName-")

            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
            }
        }

}

    }
```

This will give the output as **YourName-debug.apk or YourName-release-unsigned.apk**

**3)** To change the name completely you have to replace the following line with the other one.

**project.ext { appName = 'YourName' }

                def newName = output.outputFile.name.replace("android", "$project.ext.appName-")** replace to

**def newName = output.outputFile.name.replace("android-release-unsigned", "$project.ext.appName-"+"whatever name you wanted")** **or** for debug

**def newName = output.outputFile.name.replace("android-debug", "$project.ext.appName-"+"whatever name you wanted")**

**NOTE-1**:By changing the whole name, the problem I came through is  wont get the apk generated/location in the line ***Built the following apk(s):***. This line will be empty but your apk will be generated and file location is same, as in mine(**platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/YourName-whatevernameyouwanted.apk**).

**NOTE-2**: Im using **command-prompt** to build these stuffs. Once you made changes to your **build.gradle** file you just save it which will reflect in your **command-prompt**. Its not like **android studio/eclipse** where when you edit the **build.gradle** file you have to **resync** the file again.